# Finding linked files

Tags: 14.04, bash, find

Trying to find where `/usr/include/freetype2/ft2build.h` file is linked in my system:

```
sudo find -L / -samefile /usr/include/freetype2/ft2build.h
```

This dives many errors `File system loop detected`

```
find: File system loop detected; `/sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/node0/memory0/subsystem/devices/memory2/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/PNP0303:00/physical_node/subsystem/devices/00:06/tty/ttyS0/subsystem/ttyS2/device/subsystem/devices/i8042/serio1/subsystem/drivers/atkbd/serio0/input/input1/device' is part of the same file system loop as `/sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/node0/memory0/subsystem/devices/memory2/firmware_node/subsystem/devices/PNP0303:00/physical_node/subsystem/devices/00:06/tty/ttyS0/subsystem/ttyS2/device/subsystem/devices/i8042/serio1/subsystem/drivers/atkbd/serio0'.
```

I have no idea what is `File system loop`, but I suppose it is not related what i'm seeking for. So, I decided to filter this error by command:

```
sudo find -L / -samefile /usr/include/freetype2/ft2build.h |grep -v File system loop detected
```

But this is not removes errors from output.

What is `File system loop` and what is wrong with my grep?

Comment: Use `find -xdev` to exclude other filesystems (including `/proc`, `/sys`, etc., which really shouldn't be probed thus).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a filesystem loop:

```
/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-mode -> /lib/recovery-mode
```

As you can see `/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-mode` is symbolic link to the directory `/lib/recovery-mode`.

`find` is already searching in `/lib/recovery-mode`, so there is no point of following the symlink `/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-mode` to search in the same place `/lib/recovery-mode` again.

This is the reason why `find` is showing the filesystem looping message, you can ignore this message as `find` will skip this symlink and keep continuing.

The errors are showing on STDERR, not STDOUT, so you need to use `grep` on STDERR.

There are many ways to achieve that, the easiest would be to send both STDOUT and STDERR to `grep`:

```
sudo find .... |& grep -v 'File system loop detected'
```